# I accidentally set an object as camera, how do I undo this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, camera

I have a problem with rendering in cycles.
In blender render my object is rendering fine, but in cycles when I pushed <kbd>F12</kbd> I got only this:

[image]

One more thing: when I click <kbd>0</kbd> on keyboard I'm not in camera persp, but in object as camera, it looks like invisible layer, I don't know how to undo this, and be in camera persp again.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) your .blend file.

Comment: If you just switched from BI to Cycles you probably don't have materials defined for Cycles, you need to recreate the materials in Cycles nodes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you accidentally set an **Object as Camera** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> will do that)

[image]

You have two options to reset the camera back to the "active camera"

- In properties windows/scene select your camera as "camera"

[image]

[image]

- Or on the 3D layout select the camera and press
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> (or use the menu: View->Cameras->Select_Active_Object_as_Camera)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. But when I set camera as camera, blender automatically changes it to the same object.

Comment: P.S. I found a solution, this is the link for someone has the same problem: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209624/my-camera-is-set-to-an-object-and-every-time-i-change-that-it-automatically-go

Answer (score 2):

Zoom out or select a camera from the outliner and press Ctrl Numpad 0.