# How do I un make my object the camera?

Tags: camera

I was pushing random buttons and all of the sudden my monkey was the camera. How do I undo this?[image]

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46487/19287

Comment: Your camera is inside the monkey "Suzanne". Select the camera in the "Outliner" press "G" to grab it and move it away from Suzanne. You can also select Suzanne and press "H" to hide it. You'll then be able to see your camera to move it. Then press ALT + H to un-hide Suzanne.