# View camera not correct

Tags: camera

The camera is placed to see my scene from the front, like this:

[image]

But if I got to view and then camera, this is what I see:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you upload your .blend using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com please? Thanks

Comment: I added the blend file, I find out that If I delete my ButterflyComponents the view is fine. What is my problem?

Comment: @Repolho Please do not edit out the content of the question.  Others who visit the site now with similar problems to what you describe will not be able to easily see if this question/answer(s) will help them.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46487/i-accidentally-set-an-object-as-camera-how-do-i-undo-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you do not have the camera set up as the active camera, you have an object set as camera.

[image]

So, select the camera by opening up the tree (left click on it):

[image: Select camera]

Now, set it as the active camera by going to View -> Cameras -> Set Active Object as Camera.

[image: Set active]

Now you should have the camera working (as in it moves around in the animation)!  Jumping to a frame, it looks like this:

[image: Final view]

Comment: @Repolho No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You changed the camera in the scene to be an object, check the image below, you need to go to Scene menu, change it back to be Camera.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to resolve. I tried solutions in earlier replies, but it didn't work somehow. Maybe because my camera had animations on it. Here is what I did -

Checked the Use Local Camera in the view panel on the right (which appeared when we press n) and the at the Local Camera field, choose Camera.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, I made assets file for the new assets library used in blender 3.0. I have my camera setup for the item I am making as a asset. Normally it creates the picture on it's own but sometimes I have to do manually. The issue is I just made a new group of items as assets. It would not automatically create the thumbnail So I did manually except it would not take a picture of the correct item. I tried everything from deleting the hiearchy to deleting all artifacts of camera's in the scene, and adding new camera's... nothing worked. Then I noticed that the new items were not in a folder like everything else so I created one and put new items in it. Picked an item in another folder turning off the new folder and it worked. Now I know what's happening. I forgot to turn off camera's for render for new items I did not want to be in the picture, maybe it's makes it a new issue however it screwed me up so maybe someone else might have the same issue