# Rendering Animation from camera perspective

Tags: rendering, camera

I made an animation and rendered it. However, when i watched the animation, the camera stayed in 1 position, and did not follow the paths I gave the camera in blender. I see a "Camera Persp" view on the top right of my screen, and thats how i want it to be rendered. Any ideas how i can fix this? thanks!

Comment: Welcome to BSE. It would be helpful if you uploaded your .blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: are there other cameras on the scene? Is an object set as camera? Maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46487/i-accidentally-set-an-object-as-camera-how-do-i-undo-this or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55513/view-camera-not-correct/55516#55516