# ctrl+alt+0 moves geometry for me

Tags: camera

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, trying to move the camera to the current view I end up in a view like this:

[image: puzzling result of ctrl+alt+0]

and when I after some struggling comes back to controlling the 3d view again, I can see that my geometry has moved, far far away, into another galaxy.

What can I possibly have done to let this happen?

[image: The geometry has been displaced]

Comment: Please read the answer to [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46487/i-accidentally-set-an-object-as-camera-how-do-i-undo-this), it should help. You have set an object as your camera.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> moves the **Active Camera** to the current viewport position.

For this to work there have to both be a camera in the scene **and** the camera must be set as active object.

If some other random object is incorrectly set as active camera that object will be moved instead.

Either add a new camera to your scene and make it active, or make an existing one active for the scene by selecting the camera object and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

If you want to keep the current view you can then press again <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to return to the previous state and finally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to bring the now active camera to line up with the current view.

Answer (score 1):

You had the object selected not the camera

Select the camera you want to apply and than do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> again

Comment: Does not seem to matter actually.

Comment: sorry let me correct myself: You hit only CTRL + 0 => applying the camera function to the selected object

Comment: When I press Ctrl+0, its like I am pressing Ctrl+Alt+0.

Comment: Than you moved arround (while your camera is still applied to the object) .. than when you pressed CTR + ALT + 0 you moved the "active Camera" (saying the object instead of the camera) to the view position

Comment: What is "applying camera to object"?

Comment: I never had to select the camera before, the functionality has been to simple move the camera so it will see the object like I am currently doing.

Comment: I mean with that CTRL  + 0 sets any selected object as "active camera". So that any camera relative movement (like also the flight mode) will apllie to this object.

to fix now: Select the camera and press CTRL + 0. Than you can set the camera again to your view with CRTL + ALT + 0 as you expect

Comment: I am trying to select the camera, then when my mouse is hovering the 3d view, I hit Ctrl+0, but that will change the view to the camera, without moving it.

Comment: Now, ctrl+alt+0 works as expected, I did not even have to choose the camera, must be a bug.

Comment: yes but this is what should happen.

CTRL + 0 "makes" the selected Object the "active Camera".

CTRL+ ALT + 0 than will move any object that in this moment is marked as "active Camera" to fit the view you have. I'm sorry this sounds so confusing :D Just try it again playing with the CTRL + 0 and selecting different objects you will see what I mean

Comment: @derHugo Could you please rephrase your question and clarify what you mean? Please edit it and include all this information in the post.