# Camera Mode is fixed to a point independent to where the camera is

Tags: camera, shortcut

I was following a tutorial about cameras and lightning. At certain point the shortcut Ctrl Alt Numpad 0 was introduced. This shortcut was about moving the camera to the point I was looking at.

The strange thing is that the camera did not moved to that point, but every time I switch to camera view mode with Numpad 0. It goes to that point. Even when I remove all cameras from the scene, that point is the camera view.

Bellow is a print screen showing the view point when I click on Numpad 0. You can see that the camera is somewhere else.
[image]

Can someone tell me what am I looking through when I click on Numpad 0 if there is no camera set at that point. Also if I have no camera on the scene, why is Numpad 0 even working.

References:

Tutorial Link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rbPwn-I0oM

Comment: If you look at the top left of the image you will clearly see "object as caemera". To make the camera the active camera in the scene, select it and press ctrl+numpad 0

Comment: Duplicate of: [I accidentally set an object as camera, how do I undo this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46487/i-accidentally-set-an-object-as-camera-how-do-i-undo-this/46490#46490)

Comment: Press Ctrl+` this shows all layers. Press Z to wire frame. Slide down Outliner to see all objects in scene. Find the object that you thing is the camera object and delete it.

Comment: @OthoapProto there is no need to delete anything. You can set the camera as active camera again.