# For some very weird reason, blender uses my plane object as a camera. possible bug?

Tags: objects, camera

I do not know if this is a bug or not, but I just went onto blender this afternoon, and I am not sure what the heck I did wrong, but all of a sudden, whenever I pressed Numpad 0, (which is the hotkey to see through the camera's perspective,) it took me into the object's perspective, as if the object were a camera itself, even though I already have a real camera in the scene.  Sorry if I worded that weird, but basically, my problem is that I need to be able to look through the perspective of my actual camera, and not my plane object.

also, whenever I press the "camera to view" button, it rotates and moves my plane object around as if it were the camera.  I've made sure that I have no camera objects that are parented to the mesh, so I have no clue what the heck is happening.

I will give a link to my file below, although if it is some sort of bug it might not work for everyone.

And before you ask, yes I have tried restarting blender and even my computer and that has changed nothing.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you clicked ctrl + alt + 0 and set the active object as camera?

Comment: I might have.  If I did, how would I undo that?

Comment: Maybe this will help - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46487/i-accidentally-set-an-object-as-camera-how-do-i-undo-this?noredirect=1&lq=1
Also I meant ctrl + 0 xD

Comment: Thanks! That worked