# My camera is set to an object, and every time i change that, it automatically goes back to the object when i click render

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

When ever this normally happens i go the the scene tab in properties and just change the camera, or i go to view-camera-set active camera and it works fine but now, when i click render it switches the camera back to the object/rig. not sure why, this is an animation, I don't know if that effects anything

[image: I dont know what this is]

[image: heres what its set tp]

Comment: Select this camera and make it **active** with CTRL 0 before you render.

Comment: I have tried that, it doesnt work

Comment: So this may be a bug or the shortcut is different (in that case you can use 2.7x shortcuts)

Comment: maybe you have an object constraint (track to) ?

Comment: The scene will render using whatever you have set as camera. In the scene section, pictured on the question, select the camera instead of the rig.

Answer (score 3):

You've bound the camera to a marker.

[image]

And the active camera is not a camera, but an object.

When you [*bind* a camera to a marker](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/markers.html?highlight=bind%20camera#bind-camera-to-markers), it becomes the active camera starting on that frame in the timeline. Binding cameras allows you to switch cameras at a certain point in the animation. But since there are no other active cameras bound to other markers, the object becomes the only camera that will be used for rendering the whole scene.

To fix it just delete the marker. Go to the frame where the marker is and Select *marker* > ***Delete Marker***

[image]

From the [blender manual:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/markers.html?highlight=bind%20camera#bind-camera-to-markers)

> ***Bind Camera to Markers*** is a special operator only available in the Timeline. The operator allows markers to be used to set the active object as the active camera.
> To use this operator, select the object to become the active camera and select a marker to bind the active camera to. If no marker is selected when the operator is applied, a marker will be added. When an object is bound to a marker, the marker will be renamed to the name of the active object. These markers also have a camera icon next to the left of the name to easily distinguish them from other informative markers.
> These markers can be moved to change the frame at which the active camera is changed to the object the marker is bound to.

Comment: Thank you susu! This was exactly what was driving me nuts for half an hour. I did not understand what kept changing my scene's active camera when I hit render. Turns out the object was set as a camera in the timeline. I assume it can happen when accidentally dragging an object into the timeline in a specific way.

Answer (score -1):

Found a way round it, changed the setting so i cannot see any bones on the rig then rendered it from the view page!

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail how you did that? Perhaps post a few screenshots of the procedure and result