# My Camera thinks my Mesh is my Camera?

Tags: camera

so I'm new to Blender and doing the good old donut tutorial.

Now I'm having troubles with setting up the camera.

So my donut is at the cursor (xyz 0). Then Ctrl+A>New camera. G>Z camera up.
[image]

By pressing Num0 I'm not going in cameraview but in "donutview". Blender things my donut is the camera?

[image]

When I rotate (Mouse Middle) my donut moves, without me pressing any key. So if I press Num1 my donut is not at xyz0 but somewhere else. However my Camera is at the same position.

[image]

If I'm pressing Ctrl+Alt+Num0 (to snap camera to view) the same thing happens except my donut is even further gone.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Optionaly there is a video where I show the problem:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqBi607WUChHfY6ioVUrduXjwp8?e=uiANYH

Comment: Maybe your problem is that you've selected another object as camera. To select the camera back, select it and press Ctrl 0 instead of 0 only

Comment: Hi, Marian, thanks for the work you've put into editing your question. You weren't to know, but it turns out to be a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46487/35559.  I hope that fixes everything for you.

Comment: Robin Betts thank you! I figuered it out myself just minutes after editing the question.^^

Comment: Thanks, @Marian! .. Nothing personal .. we'll 'close the case', as a duplicate, to keep the archive as tidy as we can.