# Instead of my primary view being the camera itself it is the icing of the donut. And if I try to render it since the icing is the camera it glitches.h

Tags: rendering

I fixed my original mistake, but then another one popped up. Instead of my primary view being the camera itself, it is the icing of the donut. How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello it is hard to understand what you mean, if you mean that the icing is used as camera (?), select the camera and Ctrl 0

Comment: Here is what I mean by the icing is used as the camera. (in another picture)

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=zWMMegWV" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zWMMegWV/)

Comment: In the Scene panel > Scene > Camera, as you see you've selected the object called icing.001 as camera, instead select the camera

Comment: See the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46487/i-accidentally-set-an-object-as-camera-how-do-i-undo-this

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed everything. I feel kinda dumb now.